# created two- directed relationships in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, relationship, directed-graph

I'm trying to create one directed relationship if user_1<-FOLLOWS-> user_2. 
When I'm using the following cypher it creates those relationships duplicated as user1-[FOLLOWS]->user2
and user1<-[:FOLLOWS]-user2.

```
LOAD CSV with headers FROM "file:///a.csv" AS profile FIELDTERMINATOR';'
 MATCH (n1:Profile {id:trim(profile.fromId)})
   MATCH (n2:Profile {id:trim(profile.ToId)})
   MERGE (n1)-[:FOLLOWS]->(n2);
```

Have you got any ideas instead of creating double time the same type of relationship?

Comment: are you sure your csv file does not have have rows with the same values that are different only in their order? For example: 1,2 and 2,1. Otherwise your cypher should not create duplicate relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Undirected  graph support in neo4j . But there is support for pattern match without direction .i.e : you can query like ,
`MATCH (n1)-[:FOLLOWS]-(n2) or MERGE (n1)-[:FOLLOWS]-(n2)`.
So , there is no need for undirected graph when there is scope for matching without giving direction.

so in your case , if you do like this, it wont create duplicate relations

```
   MATCH (n1:Profile {id:trim(profile.fromId)})
   MATCH (n2:Profile {id:trim(profile.ToId)})
   MERGE (n1)-[:FOLLOWS]-(n2)
```